# If a white light is incident on a thin prism, that means all colors have the same incident angle

Tags: optics, geometric-optics

If a white light is incident on a face of a thin prism, then all colors have the same incident angle. A dispersion occurs in the prism, but only the ray of one color will be parallel to the base of the prism assuming the state of minimum deviation. However, a thin prism is always in the state of minimum derivation, so that means all colors not just one assume minimum deviation. My explanation to this is that because the prism is thin, one might assume that the dispersion inside it is so small that one can neglect it, making all colors parallel to the prism base, and being, therefore, in the state of minimum derivation, is that correct?

Comment: It is a small angle approximation but if you look hard enough you will observe dispersion as for a lens when it is called [chromatic aberration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromatic_aberration).